# JDBC performance when connection is stablished

Tags: java, database, performance, jdbc, database-connection

I want to reduce the time of part of project that currently takes 2 hrs.

How it has been coded is it goes and take out almost 700,000 UID from one table and pass it to 16 different threads. Each thread then connect to JDBC and fetch a row for a UID one by one. it runs 700,000 query! 50k for each thread

Because it uses 3 to 4 fields of each row my plan is to get the needed fields at first and don't connect to database anymore.
my concerns:

- because it fetch a row by UID ( I assume this should be fast) does it improve performance dramatically ?
- I need to worry about memory and cache misses and everything, putting 700,000 rows with couple of fields in memory scares me.

Overall do you think this will help to improve the performance or you think it doesn't matter that much. saving 5min  because of testing necessary it doesn't worth it.

So do you think I should pursue this path or focus more on logic???

Thanks a lot

Comment: If the average size of each row is quite small (i.e. you can fit 700,000 rows in memory) then it would be much faster to select the lot into memory and then run your threads (if each row took 1K bytes, you'd only need about 700Mb spare)

Comment: 700Mb is fine for the memory but I will get some cache misses. can you give me a estimate on how long running each SQL takes to get a row with known UID?

Comment: Even fetching row by UID is very fast, you don't want to fetch each row individually. If possible, fetch a couple of them every time. 700,000 queries are just too much.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I'm not sure what kind of cache it is, but I'm sure it can be 700Mb! so I know I get some cache misses every lets assume 64 times (cache slots of 64k with 1k each row) and because I don't have any clue how long it takes to fetch a row from DB I don't know if it worth it or not!

Comment: Are you using a JDBC connection pooling framework (e.g. dbcp, etc.)? If not, you should consider it. If so, do you have a large enough pool that you are actually able to get a concurrency advantage from your 16 threads?

Comment: I assume you mean database cache of recently/frequently accessed data, and you think that database will go often to disc to fetch data. Well, sure, that is one of the concerns when going 700 000 times to DB, besides the cumulative network latency to fetch each row individually. The general solution is to fetch and process the rows in larger chunks.

Comment: @pens-fan-69 it use DataSource and JdbcTemplate, my assumption was that spring will take care of it , right?

Comment: @Mars that depends on how you configured the data source. See this page (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-spring-config-connpooling.html) for an example of how to configure the data source to use dpcp (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp) with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been suggested in various comments, you should load the records in batches. I don't know how your infrastructure is configured, but if you are using a cloud service, a database round trip can take on the order of hundreds of milliseconds.

However, that may not be your only problem. If you haven't configured connection pooling, it may well be that you are gaining nothing from your multi-threading as each thread waits to grab the database connection. Your pool size should take into account how many connections may be established concurrently (in this case, it sounds like 17 may be your number - 1 for the main thread and 16 for the workers - if I understand your architecture correctly).

Comment: Though this isn't part of the answer to your question, I would suggest you might realize better performance by having a main server thread read chunks of records and then multiplex the rows to the threads for processing rather than having each thread read rows singly.

Comment: it was my idea to do that too, but it needs lots of change and coding in my end. and I wanted to be sure it help a lot then do it.

Comment: we use BasicDataSource with   <property name="initialSize" value="1" />     <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" /> do you know if it creates more connection when it needs it or it will stick to initialsize? thanks a lot

Comment: default is max 8 thanks

Comment: @Mars, as you have already found, 8 is the maximum connections by default, assuming you are using the DBCP `BasicDataSource` (which it sounds like you are). Given that you are using a connection pool (though perhaps underconfigured a little) I think you will need to rearchitect your solution if you want to realize a substantial performance gain.